# How to maintain connection in Socket after using NetworkStream c#

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, connection, networkstream

Simple I try to send a file to a server then send a file from server to client using networkstreams (only for files). The code shown is only server side, first one gets a file from client, second sends a file to client

---

```
   try
                {
                    using (var netStream = new NetworkStream(current, false))
                    {
                        netStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(cp.parameters[0] + "\\" + cp.parameters[0] + ".txt"))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyFrom(netStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

After this i try to execute this piece of code but it says on SocketException that I cannot use it because it's not connected. In debug for the socket "current" i see the .Connected variable is set to false but the IPEndpoints and ports for both sides are still the correct ones only the .Connected status is false.

---

```
try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Text is a payloadx64file request");
                    using (var netStream = new NetworkStream(current, false))
                    {
                        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("Payload_x64.zip"))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(netStream);
                            Console.WriteLine(fileStream.Name);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

---

How do i use the Socket with a network stream but prevent it to close down after garbage collector or block modification the variable .Connected, also as a side question

- I mention that i set the ReadTimeout to 5 seconds because if there is no timeout in the Copy functions the Stream object get's stuck in a while loop because of a stream read that never ends. If someone knows how to end the loop or read please share with me too.

  ```
   while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) //here gets stuck in case someone knows
  ```

Here is the Copy code from a stream to another

```
 public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        int total = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {

            if (total <= totalFileSize)
            {
                byte[] clear_buffer = CryptosystemChiper.DecryptToByteArray(buffer);
                int size = clear_buffer.Length;
                output.Write(clear_buffer, 0, size);
                total += size;
                //Console.WriteLine("Bytes got:" + size); FROM DEBUG
                //Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total + " bytesRead is: " + bytesRead); FROM DEBUG
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total + " bytesRead is: " + bytesRead); FROM DEBUG
                //Console.WriteLine("About to break"); FROM DEBUG
                break;
            }


        }
```

Comment: If you wrap a socket in a networkstream, the expectation is that you'll be using the networkstream for the duration - you don't switch between the two. So: just keep using the networkstream

Comment: Re the read: a network stream ends (for read) when the other end closes their send socket (your receive socket), and you've consumed all the data. If the read isn't exiting: they haven't closed their send socket.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok i can try to use only networkstream for the whole program. I know that it ends when the other end closes their socket, the thing is I wanted to keep the connection open after i send a file, and keep sending strings (as commands) back and forth and responses and trigger other file transfer when needed. Thing is my program is stuck on the read function and file transfer and won't retake it's normal course and listen for the commands. I know I could just close the connection. maybe start another for the next part, but there is no way i can maintain it? I used timeout as workaround

Comment: @MarcGravell Also I read on Microsoft site that i can use a 2nd parameter (the false one) to set ownership on the socket. If i set ownership false like in the code then when the GarbageCollector destroy the NetworkStream shouldn't the socket remain untouched because of the ownership flag set to False? This is a thing I don't understand about it's counstructor even after i read the documentation

Comment: This is nothing whatsoever to do with the garbage collector. And yes, there is a flag to control ownership that impacts what Close/Dispose do, but that isn't the sticking point here. I suspect the real problem here is "framing". A TCP socket is a logical byte stream, which means all it guarantees is the order of the data. Not anything else. I suspect the real problem here is that whatever is sending this data is not including a "frame" to say when the file payload ends. For example, a simple prefix that says "the next payload is 42092 bytes", so you read that many before changing mode.

Comment: @MarcGravell I added the code how i copy from a stream to another stream. Thing is i already have the file size and file name before i use this function. The other thing is...... this IF is useless because it still gets stuck on the last read. (Mentioning that i already got all the file and the last read does nothing really)

Comment: you should check the total length *before* the read, so you can break out; otherwise, you'll never get to that check

Comment: Ok, I put the checking condition on the While loop, i changed the code instead of using network socket only in a little scope inside a "use" to make it global or on the whole function, I deleted the ReadTimeout and keep it on infinite. Tested it and it works just fine now finally. I still don't understand why or what does make the socket.Connected property false on the old code but now it works. You said the GarbageCollector will not change the socket if ownership is false so this means the ReadTimeout IOException sets it to false but i still don't know really what happens. It works now atleas

Comment: I will write an awnser to this question myself when I have a bit of time to sort it out and explain in detail what happens